# ¿Es posible declarar un IF en SQL como variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, condiciones

¡Hola a todos!

Tengo una duda . Resulta que tengo una consulta en la cual hago un if para sacar un valor

`if(esto = aquello, variable - x, variable) as numero`

Pero luego esta nueva variable "numero" la vuelvo a usar en otra instancia dentro de la misma sentencia.

```
(if(esto = aquello, variable - x, variable) + Y) as numero2
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que pueda hacer `"(numero + Y) as numero2"` y no `(if(esto = aquello, variable - x, variable) + Y) as numero2`

Comment: No se puede. No hay forma de guardar valores dentro de un query para que sean leidos en si mismo. Las bases de datos procesan los datos de entrada y generan una salida, una fila a la vez. Pero no revisan que pasa en cada campo.. no saben que queres hacer algo con un valor que calculaste en otro campo. Si necesitas calcularlo, lo tenes que calcular todas las veces.

Comment: existe algo muy similar que se llama CASE, podrías darle un vistazo

Comment: agrego la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) que propone @KevinDelva

Comment: @gbianchi y que hay de los ? hasta donde sé permiten variables dinámicas en Oracle y PostgreSQL ( Al menos así lo veo, soy Fullstack no especialista de datos )

Comment: de que ? hablas? de los que usas para pasarle parametros? @RuslanLópez

Comment: efectivamente, los parámetros lo hacen dinámico

Comment: No son variables dinamicas @RuslanLópez, son parametros, y te puedo asegurar que la libreria que dispara la query a la db los manda reemplazados ya.. no hay nada dinamico en esa query..

Comment: @gbianchi cual librería?

Comment: La que hace l query. Como los usas si no?